# Node.js best practice check for file exists

Tags: node.js

What is the best practise to check if a file exists with Node.js?

In other questions on here I see alot of answers saying to use `fs.exists`

But the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) say:

> In particular, checking if a file exists before opening it is an anti-pattern that leaves you vulnerable to race conditions: another process may remove the file between the calls to fs.exists() and fs.open(). Just open the file and handle the error when it's not there.

What happends when you open a file? Does it stay open untill you close it (is this a leak?)? So, do you have to close the file after you opened it? And if I use `fs.exists` do I open the file too?

Does this mean the best way to check if a file exists is:

```
fs.open('path/file.js', function(err, fd) {
    if (err && err.code == 'ENOENT') {
        // Does not exist
    } else if (!err) {
        // Does exist
        fs.close(fd);
    } else {
        // Some other error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happends when you open a file? Does it stay open untill you close it (is this a leak?)?

Yes, if you open a file you must close it.  Otherwise it will remain open until your process dies.

> And if I use fs.exists do I open the file too?

Simply calling `fs.exists()` does not open the file, so there is nothing to close.

If you have a reason for only checking to see if a file exists, you should use `fs.exists()`.  The documentation is saying that if what you really want to do is open a file, there is no need to check `fs.exists()` beforehand.  If you want to open a file, just try to open it and handle the errors.

Comment: In the docs it also says: fs.exists() is an anachronism and exists only for historical reasons. Is this something to worry about?

Comment: @Klaasvaak I wouldn't worry about it.  There are certainly reasons you may want to check for a file existing... Again, I think they are trying to warn against people using it when they don't need to, prior to opening files.

Comment: @Klaasvaak here is a thing to worry about: as you can see the callback  for `exists` doesn't accept error as other `fs` callbacks do. I had situations where `exists` caused errors and `domain` was the only way to catch them

Comment: @vkurchatkin Can you tell me what kind of situations?

Comment: @Klaasvaak I wish I knew for sure. Most likely that happened when I tried to check for existing file which was already opened by the same process.

Comment: @Klaasvaak after looking the code of `exists`, I take my words back, it was probably not `exists` error. `exists` just calls `stat` and checks the `err`, so you can actually do that yourself.